# Continuity for absolute value function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

These are true/false questions.

1. If f is continuous on the open interval I, then |f| is continuous on I.
2. If |f| is continuous on the open interval I, then f is continuous on I.

I need help picturing these, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can consider $x,| x| $

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: I am not sure this will suffice for 2.

Comment: First statement is true but second one is false. If $f(x)$ = {$1$ if x is rational, $-1$ otherwise$}$ Notice that this function isn't continuous but $|f(x)|=1$ which is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. This is a composition of continuous functions
2. Can you think of a function which is not constant but whose absolute value is constant? Note that $|-1|=|1|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)\implies\lim_{x\to c}|f(x)|=|f(c)|$, because $\left||a|-|b|\right|\le|a-b|$.
2. if $|f(x)|>0$, jumping from $f(x)$ to $-f(x)$ creates a discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, note that 
$$
||f(x)| - |f(c)|| \leq |f(x) - f(c)|;
$$
so $f$ continuous implies $|f|$ is continuous.

For the second question, consider the function $f: x \mapsto 1$ on $]0,1[$ and $\mapsto -1$ on $\{ 1 \}$ and $\mapsto 1$ on $]1, 2[$. Then the domain of $f$ is the open interval $]0, 2[$ and $|f|$, being a constant function, is continuous on $]0,2[$; but $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 1$. You can see the discontinuity by taking $\varepsilon := 1/2$, say.